# How to Write a valid Class Decorator in Python?

Tags: python, class, scope, closures, decorator

I just wrote a class decorator like below, tried to add debug support for every method in the target class:

```
import unittest
import inspect

def Debug(targetCls):
   for name, func in inspect.getmembers(targetCls, inspect.ismethod):
      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         print ("Start debug support for %s.%s()" % (targetCls.__name__, name));
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
         return result
      setattr(targetCls, name, wrapper)
   return targetCls

@Debug
class MyTestClass:
   def TestMethod1(self):
      print 'TestMethod1'

   def TestMethod2(self):
      print 'TestMethod2'

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

   def testName(self):
      for name, func in inspect.getmembers(MyTestClass, inspect.ismethod):
         print name, func

      print '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
      testCls = MyTestClass()

      testCls.TestMethod1()
      testCls.TestMethod2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
   unittest.main()
```

Run above code, the result is:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

TestMethod1 <unbound method MyTestClass.wrapper>
TestMethod2 <unbound method MyTestClass.wrapper>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Start debug support for MyTestClass.TestMethod2()
TestMethod2
Start debug support for MyTestClass.TestMethod2()
TestMethod2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

OK
```

You can find that 'TestMethod2' printed twice.

Is there problem? Is my understanding right for the decorator in python?

Is there any workaround?
BTW, i don't want add decorator to every method in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this loop:

```
for name, func in inspect.getmembers(targetCls, inspect.ismethod):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print ("Start debug support for %s.%s()" % (targetCls.__name__, name))
```

When `wrapper` is eventually called, it looks up the value of `name`. Not finding it in locals(), it looks for it (and finds it) in the extended scope of the `for-loop`. But by then the `for-loop` has ended, and `name` refers to the last value in the loop, i.e. `TestMethod2`.

So both times the wrapper is called, `name` evaluates to `TestMethod2`.

The solution is to create an extended scope where `name` is bound to the right value. That can be done with a function, `closure`, with default argument values. The default argument values are evaluated *and fixed* at definition-time, and bound to the variables of the same name.

```
def Debug(targetCls):
    for name, func in inspect.getmembers(targetCls, inspect.ismethod):
        def closure(name=name,func=func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print ("Start debug support for %s.%s()" % (targetCls.__name__, name))
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                return result
            return wrapper        
        setattr(targetCls, name, closure())
    return targetCls
```

In the comments eryksun suggests an even better solution:

```
def Debug(targetCls):
    def closure(name,func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print ("Start debug support for %s.%s()" % (targetCls.__name__, name));
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper        
    for name, func in inspect.getmembers(targetCls, inspect.ismethod):
        setattr(targetCls, name, closure(name,func))
    return targetCls
```

Now `closure` only has to be parsed once. Each call to `closure(name,func)` creates its own function scope with the distinct values for `name` and `func` bound correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't writing a valid class decorator as such; the class is obviously being decorated and doesn't just raise exceptions, you get to code you intended to add to the class. So clearly you need to be looking for a bug in your decorator, not questions of whether you're managing to write a valid decorator.

In this case, the problem is with closures. In your `Debug` decorator, you loop over `name` and `func`, and for each loop iteration you define a function `wrapper`, which is a closure that *has access to the loop variables*. The problem is that as soon as the next loop iteration starts the things referred to by the loop variables has changed. But you only ever call any of these wrapper functions *after* the entire loop has done. So every decorated method ends up calling out to the *last* values from the loop: in this case, `TestMethod2`.

What I would do in this case is make a method-level decorator, but as you don't want to explicitly decorate every method you then make a class decorator that goes through all the methods and passes them to the method decorator. This works because you're not giving the wrapper access to your loop variable through a closure; you're instead passing a reference to the thing the loop variable referred to into a function (the decorator function which constructs and returns a wrapper); once that's done it doesn't affect the wrapper function to rebind the loop variable on the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. You think `wrapper` is a closure that captures the current `func` argument, but that is not the case. If you don't pass the current `func` value to the wrapper, it's value is only looked up after the loop, so you get the last value.

You can do this:

```
def Debug(targetCls):

   def wrap(name,func): # use the current func
      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         print ("Start debug support for %s.%s()" % (targetCls.__name__, name));
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
         return result
      return wrapper

   for name, func in inspect.getmembers(targetCls, inspect.ismethod):
      setattr(targetCls, name, wrap(name, func))
   return targetCls
```